Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath ---
Here is my code
@Test
public void validate_login() {

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']")).sendKeys("CRM708153");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).sendKeys("bRSNWey6");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@name='login']")).click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(40));
                
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'font-sm eMNotSelectable') and text()='I accept']")));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'font-sm eMNotSelectable') and text()='I accept']")).click();

I am trying to click on I accept checkbox and continue button

Share the URL of the website if it is public.

Like Shawn said please share the URL if it is public to debug more.
From given code i think you want to click the "I Accept" button/checkbox
Please check the below things to solve from my perspective it may or may not work

Check XPath is valid & highlighting in console
If it is present in alert like message we need to change approach
Founded XPath only occurs 1 time if more than occurs use indices

